# Sqlite Insert contains character â€“

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm using Sqlite.net. In the start of my C# program. I have the following code to set pragma.

```
using(SQLiteCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand()) {
cmd.CommandText = "PRAGMA encoding = \"UTF-8\"";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

When the record is inserted in table, I am seeing â€“ character instead of -. My table column is NVARCHAR(1024). I will try more but I am curious if others have similar issue.

Comment: Ahh.. apparently UTF-8 is default. The problem is not my program but the Sql Admin tool i used. Using source forge DB admin tool works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html) docs:

> It is not possible to change the text encoding of a database after it has been created and any attempt to do so will be silently ignored.

In other words, you need to do that when you create your database.

Comment: And the database encoding does *not* affect the encoding used in SQL queries.